# String equivalent of =+ but existing string as appended rather than prepended to new string

Tags: python, string, operators, pycharm

I'm using PyCharm (version 4.0.3) and getting a style warning *Assignment can be replaced with augmented assignment*  on the second line of the following code*:

```
abc = 'and cheese'
abc = 'ham' + abc
```

* - My code is not really this code but it generates the same error. I am programmatically generating two strings and I have to / would like to generate the first line (second part of the English syntax) before the second line (the first part of the English syntax).

But I don't know what augmented assignment could do this.  If the code were like this (where the first part of the desired final string could be generated first in execution order)

```
abc = 'ham'
abc = abc + 'and cheese'
```

then I believe the problem is trivially resolved with the += operator:

```
abc = 'ham'
abc += 'and cheese'
```

But in the context of my problem (where the 'and cheese' part is declared before 'ham'), is there a way to satisfy this warning?

Comment: This sounds like a bug in PyCharm, but that seems unlikely - could you post your actual code so we can be sure?

Comment: The code I provide generates the same warning in PyCharm

Comment: I'm at a loss to explain it then, my best guess is a bug in PyCharm. Hopefully someone else has a better answer :-(

Comment: Bro, this is the problem with string concatenation. Use `format` always.... The problem is (I think, it considers you are doin arithmetic `+` and not concat and so the problem)

Comment: @BhargavRao - `format` doesn't do in-place operations. And string concatenation is generally acceptable.

Comment: @tdelaney What about `abc = 'ham {}'.format(abc)`

Comment: @BhargavRao: do you mean the problem with string concatenation is that it isn't commutative, or the problem with string concatenation is that PyCharm doesn't understand it? ;-)

Comment: @BhargavRao - pycharm says the operation can be replaced with augmented assignment, that's what the question is about. OP is already doing concatenation, which is fine.

Comment: @SteveJessop I am with you on the second point.

Comment: Presumably PyCharm doesn't get equally confused by `x = y / x` and claim you could replace that with augmented assignment, since it doesn't expect `/` to be commutative.

Comment: @tdelaney Yeah, That's what I meant to say. The prob is with PyCharm

Comment: @SteveJessop Ok. Then why on earth is it gettin confused with `+`? Is it bcoz arithmetic `+` is commutative?

Comment: I'm using PyCharm 4.0.1 and I do not get this warning.

Comment: @BhargavRao: that's my guess, but I don't use PyCharm so I can't check for myself what tickles it (still less in what versions of PyCharm). The hint is clearly wrong in this case, so I'm guessing that it's over-eager about the properties of `+` since that makes at least *some* kind of sense. It could just as well be a complete facepalm bug due to a typo in the PyCharm source or whatever :-)

Comment: @SteveJessop Yeah, Perhaps we may get a clue in bug reports of PyCharm (if any) ...

Comment: But then if Pycharm has to consider the fact that any operator may be overloaded and loose any commutative property it may have had (as I think it should), this type of inspection is definitely broken, isn't it ? Especially since there are also reflected operators

Comment: I am still getting this in 4.0.4

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are more than one way to skin a cat (or to con**cat**enate strings).

You can concatenate using `str.join` but it may be marginally less efficient for small lists:

```
abc = " ".join((abc, 'and cheese'))
```

Or using format:

```
abc = "{} {}".format(abc, 'and cheese')
```

But really, the correct way to silence the warning is to submit a bug report for the IDE, because it looks like there is nothing wrong with your code (someone in the comments already pointed out it is not reproducible on the last version).

Comment: Oh, if your version is newer then it looks like a regression on their Python linter.